# CSV remove column by header name

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working on a little PowerShell script that should remove a named column. Is there a way to not NOT select a column with header name "xyz"?

I tried to get the header names by

```
$hnames = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | foreach {$_.name}
```

and join the result into a comma separated string and remove the unwanted header

```
$new = $hnames -join ","
$new = $new -replace "xyz,", ""
```

and import/export the CSV with `select`

```
Import-CSV $tempfile -Delimiter ";" | Select $new |
    Export-Csv tempynew.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInfo
```

but it only outputs the header in the CSV file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `-ExcludeProperty` parameter with [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) instead:

```
Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter ";" | Select * -ExcludeProperty xyz |
    Export-Csv tempynew.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -notypeinfo
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You could also just specify columns you wish to include, like this:

```
Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter ";" | Select Column1,Column2,Column10 | Export-Csv tempynew.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -notypeinfo
```